# "выше чем ожидалось" и "меньше, чем ожидали" в справочнике Розенталя

Tags: пунктуация, сравнение, цельное-выражение

Из справочника Розенталя, [параграф 41](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146), пункт 4:

> Внутри сочетаний ***(не) больше чем, (не) меньше чем, (не) раньше чем, (не) позже чем*** и т. п., если они не содержат сравнения, запятая не ставится: *Накладные расходы оказались **выше чем** ожидалось.*
>
> Но (при наличии сравнения или сопоставления): *Гостей оказалось **меньше, чем ожидали**.*

Почему в первом случае считается, что сравнения нет, и запятая не ставится, а во втором, наоборот, считается, что есть сравнение, а значит, ставится запятая?

Answer (score 1):

1. Не обособляются обороты со значением **отклонения от ожидаемой** (или какой-либо другой) **оценки**, если они **не содержат сравнения.** В этом случае оборот можно изъять из предложения без нарушения его структуры:  Работу можно выполнить (меньше чем) за час. Вы были для меня (больше чем) другом.
2. В других случаях такое изъятие затруднительно, и тогда возможны **парные варианты,** например:

Гостей оказалось меньше чем ожидалось. Накладные расходы оказались выше чем ожидалось.Температура в инкубаторе не ниже чем нужно. Такие обороты легко трансформируются **в сравнительные придаточные,** где требуется обособление:

Гостей оказалось меньше, чем (мы) ожидали. Накладные расходы оказались выше, чем (мы) ожидали.Температура в инкубаторе не ниже, чем это нужно.

Эти варианты требуют к себе большего внимания, в некоторых случаях не исключается авторское решение, что вообще характерно для темы "Цельные по смыслу выражения".

Comment: В обоих случаях это придаточные без какой-либо трансформации. Предложение с ‟чем ожидали” так же легко трансформировать в: ‟Накладные расходы оказались выше чем (нами) ожидалось”.

Comment: Здесь сказывается влияние различных факторов. Например, запятая не ставится при использовании пассивной безличной формы (чем ожидалось).

Answer (score 0):

По примерам Розенталя можно сделать вывод, что запятая обычно ставится, если при изъятии "чем..." структура не страдает и предложение более-менее звучит:
*Гостей оказалось меньше.

Эта комната выше.

Вернулся раньше.*
Но не: *накладные расходы оказались выше*. || Оно не звучит самостоятельно.

Также играет роль лицо глагола. Неопределённое лицо в обороте с "чем" менее характерно для сравнения (*ожидалось* [не известно кем]).

Как однозначно определить, нужна ли запятая? Запятая ставится при наличии логического ударения на слове перед потенциальной запятой и паузы.

Answer (score 0):

В этом весь Розенталь: у него есть главы, где 15 пунктов можно заменить одним, а есть вот такие строчки, которые требуют детального пояснения. И более того, ты не знаешь, если тут вообще смысл. Возможно, Розенталь имел некие сомнительные представления в данном сегменте (как и любой человек мог бы) и это просто полубред.
Сколько нужно грамотеев, столетий, параллельных измерений, чтобы получить хоть сколько-нибудь приемлемый учебник по пунктуации?
Если что, мой ответ в том, что не следует исключать сомнения и иногда спрашивать себя в подобных ситуациях: а есть ли тут вообще смысл?

Comment: Могу с уверенностью сказать, что в этом электронном справочнике много правок (порой некорректных), которые к Розенталю отношения не имеют.